# iOS Phonegap webpage links embedded in iframe open system browser instead of in iframe

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, iframe, mobile

When embedding a webpage via an iframe in phonegap, any links on that webpage will open the system browser instead of the iframe. This only occurs on iOS and only on the compiled version. Android and the phonegap app for iOS work as intended as webpage links open inside the iframe.

Config.xml preferences like 'stay-in-webview' and 'Cordova.plist' appear to be deprecated out and no longer work. Also 'ChildBrowser' preference is blackberry only. Finally the 'inAppBrowser' plugin has the same issue. It loads the webpage just fine internally but any links will trigger Safari to open.

The issue can be re-created by simply starting a new phonegap application, embedding an iframe, and then building for iOS / exporting with xcode.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

Solution:
At least in the latest phonegap (6.0 at the moment), having the below tags enabled for compiled iOS causes this issue. My best guess is that allowing these intents inadvertently tells iOS to open any / all embedded links in Safari.

I simply removed the below tags and everything is loading properly in the iframe

`<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />`

Comment: Cordova-ios 4.1.1 was just released, I think it fixed that problem, you have to use allow-navigation to whitelist the urls you want to load on the iframe, and then you can use the allow-intent to open the rest of websites on the system browser

Comment: It has been fixed in cordova **4.2.0** which is not available atm according to: https://build.phonegap.com/current-support

Bugfix: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10942